# Get extention point contribution as text

Tags: eclipse-plugin

Is there a way to get the raw XML text which another plugin has contributed to an extension point?

The normal way to access data that is contributed to an extension point is to use `IConfigurationElement` objects:

```
IConfigurationElement[] configElems = Platform.getExtensionRegistry()
    .getConfigurationElementsFor(LANGUAGES_EXTENTION_POINT_ID);
```

But I already have JAXB parser for the kind of data that is contributed to this extension point. I'd like to use that one instead of Eclipse's classes.

---

**EDIT 1:** An alternative would be to use some kind of Eclipse-configuratoin-to-JAXB bridge library. But I don't find any.

**EDIT 2:** It's probably possible to find the `plugin.xml` of the contributing plug-in and read that manually... Probably not a good idea.

**EDIT 3:** I think I will do this: Instead of contributing the data directly clients get to give a file name. I then read that file using my old parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I don't see anything that would give you the XML.

`getConfigurationElementsFor` gives you information extracted from many different plugin.xml files so it is not clear what XML could be returned anyway.

`org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry` is the extension registry implementation, but a lot of the information that uses comes from `org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.RegistryObjectManager`.